# Scheme, higher order functions, and curried functions

Tags: scheme, higher-order-functions, currying

I need to write a Scheme higher-order function that takes a function of two parameters as its parameter and returns a curried version of the function. I understand this much so far in terms of curried functions:

```
(define curriedFunction (lambda (x) 
        (if (positive? x)
            (lambda (y z) (+ x y z))
            (lambda (y z) (- x y z)))))

(display ((curriedFunction -5) 4 7))
(display "\n")
(display ((curriedFunction 5) 4 7))
```

If x is negative, it subtracts x y and z. If x is positive, it adds x, y, and z.

In terms of higher order functions I understand this:

```
(display (map (lambda (x y) (* x y)) '(1 2 3) '(3 4 5)))
```

And thirdly I understand this much in terms of passing functions in as arguments:

```
(define (function0 func x y)
        (func x y))

(define myFunction (lambda (x y)
        (* x y)))

(display (function0 myFunction 10 4))
```

In the code directly above, I understand that the function "myFunction" could have also been written as this:

```
(define (myFunction x y)
        (* x y))
```

So now you know where I am at in terms of Scheme programming and syntax.
Now back to answering the question of writing a Scheme higher-order function that takes a function of two parameters as its parameter and returns a curried version of the function. How do I connect these concepts together? Thank you in advance, I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
(define (curry f)
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda (y)
      (f x y))))
```

The function `curry` takes the function `f` and returns a function with a single argument x. *That* function, given a value for its argument, returns another function that takes an argument `y` and returns the result of applying the original function `f` to `x` and `y`. So, for instance, `(curry +)` returns a curried version of `+`:

```
(((curry +) 3) 4)  ;  produces 7
```

Comment: Wow, Renzo, that simple example you provided was awesome! I've been stuck on this for hours, but you have given me the epiphany. I can't thank you enough Renzo!